# How to proceed with unload event from bootstrap modal after preventing it

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am using bootstrap modal to confirm unload event from users. How do I proceed with the event, having prevented it before showing the modal to the user? Here is a code snippet:

```
window.addEventListener( 'beforeunload', function( event ){

    event.preventDefault();

    var confirmationMessage = "Are you sure you want to leave this page?";

    //Display modal to warn user
    $('#confirmationModalBody').html( confirmationMessage );
    $('#confirmationModalHeader').find('#H4').html( 'Confirm' );
    $('#confirmationModal').modal( { backdrop:'static' } );

    //This button with id 'confirmRequest' is what the user clicks to confirm         
    $('#confirmRequest').click( function(){

     // I intend to put the code to restore default unload event here                                       
    });
 });
```